# Late 80s early 90s TV show involving aliens had a scene where a female child or someone young looking became pregnant inexplicably and instantaneously

Tags: story-identification, aliens, horror

The only things I remember from this show are:

1. My parents wouldn't let me watch it...
2. I did... and what little I did watch terrified me.
3. All I remember from the opening sequence is ONE big flying saucer hovering over buildings.  But the perspective was from the ground looking up (like, if you were standing at the base of the building and cranking your neck up to see it).  That particular scene was at night and very dark.
4. It was NOT Alien Nation or X-Files.
5. A scene in which a panicked woman was running for some reason, and she was in-between two semi-trailers.  Then two guys showed up (one was wearing red flannel) and she was relieved for a minute until she found out they were bad guys.  Their eyes glowed or some minor transformation happened.
6. And a scene where a little girl was taken to the hospital and the doctor was shocked to find she was pregnant.  They may have done a caesarean section which revealed something alien/monstrous.
7. I'm pretty sure those two scenes are back to back and it was the same girl only she wasn't pregnant in the scene before it.  Maybe...
8. I watched it in the United States of America

That's all I can remember.  Thanks.

Comment: Could possibly be "Something is Out There", but I cannot find any scene that depicts anyone becoming pregnant.  There are a couple scenes in that mini-series/series that remind me of my memories, but I cannot be sure.

Comment: War of the Worlds?  Late 80s?

Comment: It doesn't seem dark or gritty enough. Do you recall there being a pregnant child or someone who wasn't pregnant one minute, then was the next?

Comment: What country did you see the show in?

Comment: There was also a show called "The Tripods" but I can't remember much about it :S

Comment: The United States of America.

Comment: @Beard-O: When were you a child?

Answer (score 8):

More than likely, you are recalling the first incarnation of the television show "V" with Marc Singer. You can watch the introduction to the episodes on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wa2aCC-1JEs).

Your parents probably were trying to save you from witnessing the bad acting.
Thank them.

Here is a description of the series:

> The Visitors arrive, and they seem like the most reasonable people from outer space. All they want is a few chemicals that are made from
>   waste products. They begin manufacturing these chemicals but an
>   inquisitive newsman sneaks aboard their mother ship and discovers a
>   few interesting things. It seems they just dump the chemicals out when
>   they get them, rather than storing them. They also eat live animals
>   and when their faces are pealed off they are big green lizards
>   underneath.
>
> On Earth, the Lizards plant false stories about a conspiracy among
>   scientists. People buy it, and soon are turning scientists over to the
>   police left and right. A few people realize that this is the beginning
>   of something bad and begin planning a resistance.

Comment: It's not "V".  I know that much.

Comment: Ha ha! "Your parents probably were trying to save you from witnessing the bad acting." ... yeah, but as a kid it was a fun watch.